# What are some good resources related to Geodjango?

Tags: wfs, web-service, geodjango

I am trying to learn Geodjango. Has anyone used it in their own project?

The documentation on the official site is sparse. Can someone point out the best

resources helpful in learning it other than official documentation ?

Please also tell me how is your experience with it and other web application frameworks that you have used for mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are limitid resources for geodjango or you can find only old version of documentation on net .you cant easily find to-date information about geodjango but i can give you very good source for learning it. there is great pdf presentation for it... you can learn main functions and develop your app. with it.

[1. Rapid Geographic Web Application with GeoDjango](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=geodjango%20pdf&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CDIQFjAC&url=http://geodjango.org/presentations/Rapid%2520Geographic%2520Web%2520Application%2520Development%2520with%2520GeoDjango%2520%28Where%25202.0%2520Tutorial%2520-%2520May%252013,%25202008%29.pdf&ei=Lp9ET7DqDJGb1AXSjvHrAw&usg=AFQjCNEhY6mjj-uPi8rVduh41ggOAlN2UQ&cad=rja)

[2.October 24, 2010 PyCon Ukraine Justin Bronn, Esq. - GeoDjango](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=geodjango%20pdf&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http://geodjango.org/presentations/PyCon%2520Ukraine%25202010%2520-%2520GeoDjango.pdf&ei=Lp9ET7DqDJGb1AXSjvHrAw&usg=AFQjCNEdIUncdYKS3uG7mbKfuQNY7Ge1tg&cad=rja)

[3.Django and Mapnik](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=geodjango%20pdf&source=web&cd=4&sqi=2&ved=0CDgQFjAD&url=http://dbsgeo.com/talks/wa_urisa_springmeyer_mapnik_django.pdf&ei=Lp9ET7DqDJGb1AXSjvHrAw&usg=AFQjCNGD8rf9wBc22HYjsQ68GGT6eNS6yQ&cad=rja)

i hope it helps you.

Comment: definitely better than all i know of

Comment: All these links are broken. If you could update them, it'd be super helpful. 

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The Django Project has a [GeoDjango Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

I update the links:
new links:
https://cdn.oreillystatic.com/en/assets/1/event/4/Rapid%20Geographic%20Web%20Application%20Development%20with%20GeoDjango%20Paper.pdf

https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/2002292/october-24-2010-pycon-ukraine-justin-bronn-esq-geodjango